# EXTJS || Need help in implementing the Checkbox Selection Model in the GridPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

I am facing problem while implementing the below mentioned functionality in EXTJS 4.1:

1. I have implemented **Ext.selection.CheckboxModel** to enable the user to select any row from the existing rows in the GridPanel.
2. **On click of the check box** of this selection model the User will be prompt with **EDIT & DELETE buttons** alongside the checkbox in the grid itself.
3. **On clicking EDIT**, the data from the respective(checked) row will move to the below FormPanel. Thus giving user the **privilege to alter the entered data.**
4. **On clicking DELETE**, the respective(checked) row **will be deleted from the GridPanel**.

I am able to create the checkboxes in the grid using CheckboxModel, but not able to proceed ahead with the requirement.

I have tried various examples and suggestions from the Sencha/Google, however still not able to find any solution for the same.

Any examples/pointers will be highly appreciated in this scenario.

Comment: Can you share some relevant code of what you've got so far and what have you tried?

Comment: What in particular are you having trouble executing? Were you able to get the record loaded to the form? Code would be beneficial.

Comment: Instead of button ( for EDIT & DELETE ) you can use `action` column which you can put a simple icon with appropiate click event!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would solve this problem :

Next to the checkbox column put an [actioncolumn](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action) with the two buttons. Give the actioncolumn a fixed width. Set a custom style for the two items ( buttons ), like on selected show. Style the buttons with css to display only on selected rows.

```
columns: [{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    width: 40,
    items: [{
        iconCls: 'onselect-show',
...
```

css:

```
.onselect-show {display: none;} // hide
.x-grid-row-selected .onselect-show {display: inline;} // restore default
```

By the way, I see a contradiction in your requirements. The buttons you're talking about don't make sense when more than one row is selected, but the checkbox selection model is specifically intended for multiple selection.
What about using instead `onfocused-show` together with `x-grid-row-focused` ? This would allow for multiple selections and still displaying the buttons on only one row, the one that has the focus.